# making a "poke back" program in processing

Tags: processing

x-post [Processing Forum](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/19198/trying-to-make-ellipse-poke-back)

I'm trying to make a super simple sketch where the user inputs a point with mousePressed, then (after a delay), processing plots a point at a random place on the screen back at you, and the points slowly fade into a semitransparent background. Here's my code, I've tried a bunch of different ideas but nothing seems to have worked, and now I'm at a point where nothing is working at all. Any pointers?

```java
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(0);
  stroke(color(168, 168, 168));
  strokeWeight(2);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
    }
  else if (mousePressed) {
    delay(10);
    ellipse(random(mouseX), random(mouseY),20,20);
    } 
  else {
    fill(0,55,0, 2);
    rect(0, 0, width, height, 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please link between crossposts: https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/19198/trying-to-make-ellipse-poke-back

Answer (score 1):

I would split the problem in two easier ones:

1. picking a random position (simple enough using the `random()` function)
2. slowly fading the point

To slowly fade the point there are at least a couple of options I can think of:

1. Pass a transparency value to [stroke()](https://processing.org/reference/stroke_.html) and slowly decrease this value
2. Draw a dark rectangle with a low transparency to fade the whole frame slowly rather than instantly clearing the frame

(Quick tip on `stroke()`: if you pass a single value it will be used as a grayscale value. Be sure read the reference and see what options are available for you to play with)

**Option 1:**

```
//store current transparency
int transparency = 255;
//store random x,y positions
float randomX;
float randomY;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  noFill();
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  //slowly fade out = decrease transparency
  transparency = transparency-1;
  //stop at 0 though
  if(transparency < 0) transparency = 0;

  background(0);
  stroke(168, 168, 168,transparency);
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(randomX,randomY,20,20);
}
void mousePressed(){
  //reset transparency
  transparency = 255;
  //pick random coordinates
  randomX = random(width);
  randomY = random(height);
}
```

Demo:

```js
//store current transparency
var transparency = 255;
//store random x,y positions
var randomX;
var randomY;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  noFill();
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
}

function draw() {
  //slowly fade out = decrease transparency
  transparency = transparency-1;
  //stop at 0 though
  if(transparency < 0) transparency = 0;
  
  background(0);
  stroke(168,transparency);
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(randomX,randomY,20,20);
}
function mousePressed(){
  //reset transparency
  transparency = 255;
  //pick random coordinates
  randomX = random(width);
  randomY = random(height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

**Option 2:**

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(0);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  //remove stroke
  noStroke();
  //draw a black rectangle with really low transparency
  fill(0,4);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
void mousePressed(){
  //set a stroke and draw at random coordinates 
  stroke(color(168));
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),20,20);
}
```

Demo:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  background(0);
  frameRate(60);
  smooth();
}

function draw() {
  //remove stroke
  noStroke();
  //draw a black rectangle with really low transparency
  fill(0,4);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
}
function mousePressed(){
  //set a stroke and draw at random coordinates 
  stroke(color(168));
  strokeWeight(2);
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),20,20);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.4/p5.min.js"></script>
```

With the first option, transparency affects a single dot at a time.
With the first option, transparency affects a multiple dots at a time (in fact, everything that's drawn).
There is no right/wrong, it's all up to what's closest to what your concept is about. Have fun and explore!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `delay()` function to change the timings of animations. It just causes your program to become unresponsive.

Instead, use the `frameCount` variable or the `millis()` function to record timing information, then perform your animations based on that value.

Here's an example that displays a circle for 60 frames whenever you click the mouse:

```java
int clickedFrame = -999;

void draw(){

  background(0);

  if(frameCount < clickedFrame + 60){
    ellipse(width/2, height/2, width, height);
  }
}

void mousePressed(){
  clickedFrame = frameCount;
}
```

Comment: At this point, I'm trying to have mouseClicked not only trigger an ellipse at mouseX,mouseY, but a random point on the screen after a short delay (not using the delay function as stated but having the random "answer" point show up a few seconds after).

Comment: @NickBernstein Yep, sounds good. Note that my code is just an example that you can build on. I didn't mean for it to be an entire solution.