# draw ellipse wait a few seconds and draw another one in processing

Tags: processing, wait, ellipse

So I'm using Processing and I want the program to draw one ellipse, then wait 2 seconds, then draw another different ellipse. How can I do that? 
These are the ellipses I wanna draw:

```java
    ellipse(350, 250, 160, 120); // big horizontal ellipse
    strokeWeight(8); // stroke thickness
    stroke(100); // stroke color
    noFill(); // ellipse is transparent inside

    ellipse(350, 250, 50, 120); // vertical ellipse
    strokeWeight(8); 
    stroke(100);
    noFill();

    ellipse(350, 220, 130, 50); // small horizontal ellipse
    strokeWeight(8); 
    stroke(100);
    noFill();
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `frameCount` variable or the `millis()` function to do stuff based on timing.

More info:

- [Timer using frameRate and frame counter reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666511/timer-using-framerate-and-frame-counter-reliable/44666846#44666846)
- [How to create something happen when time = x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210260/how-to-create-something-happen-when-time-x/43210363#43210363)
- [making a "poke back" program in processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727990/making-a-poke-back-program-in-processing/40728044#40728044)
- [How to add +1 to variable every 10 seconds in Processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270306/how-to-add-1-to-variable-every-10-seconds-in-processing/46271194#46271194)
- [How to make a delay in processing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570019/how-to-make-a-delay-in-processing-project/44572735#44572735)

See also: [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/)